# Am I using this readonly bindable property getter correctly?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

One of the NuGet packages I am using has the following `bindable property` available:

```
VideoStateType VideoState { get; } // The current state of the VideoView: Empty, Error, Buffering, Playing, Paused, Stopped
```

Is the code snippet below the correct implementation of "getting" the `VideoStateType`?  I've found topics regarding Read-Only Properties, but nothing related to VideoStateTypes.  I was thinking a `console.WriteLine` would help me find out, but it does not show up in my console.

Is it implemented properly?

```
private VideoStateType videoState;

public VideoStateType VideoState
{
    get 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The VideoState is ", videoState);
        return videoState; 
    }
}
```

Below is my full code if you are curious.  Basically, I have a working `isBusy` property that can be toggled `false/true` if I wish.  But I am trying to toggle `isBusy = true` only during the `buffering` VideoState.

**UPDATE: 5/20:** isBusy changed to IsBusy in `"private void Videoplayer_PropertyChanged"`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Rox;

namespace PreAppStructure
{
    public class RoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public RoxViewModel()
        {

        }

        // using "isBusy" binding.  
        // isBusy be manually toggled with:  bool isBusy = true/false;

        bool isBusy;

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return isBusy; }
            set
            {
                isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsBusy));
            }
        }

        // Attempting to get the "Video State" using the Read-Only Property

        private VideoStateType videoState;

        public VideoStateType VideoState
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The VideoState is ", videoState);
                return videoState;
            }
        }

        // Attempting to use the "Video State" in an if/else statement

        private void Videoplayer_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (videoState == VideoStateType.Buffering)
            {
                IsBusy = true; // EDIT: isBusy changed to IsBusy 
            }

            else
            {
                IsBusy = false; // EDIT: isBusy changed to IsBusy
            }
        }

        //Property Changes

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }
}
```

**XAML that hosts the binding**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PreAppStructure"
             xmlns:roxv="clr-namespace:Rox;assembly=Rox.Xamarin.Video.Portable"
             x:Class="PreAppStructure.Page3"
             Title="Welcome to page 3!">
    <Grid>
        <roxv:VideoView x:Name="VideoView" 
                        AutoPlay="True" 
                        LoopPlay="True"  
                        ShowController="True" 
                        Source="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4" 
                        PropertyChangedCommand="{Binding PropertyChangedCommand}" />

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Black" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                     VerticalOptions="Center" 
                     IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}">

            <ActivityIndicator Color="White"
                x:Name="loader"
                IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
               />

            <Label x:Name ="loadingtext" 
                   Text="Loading...Please wait!" 
                   HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                   TextColor="White" 
                   IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your XAML is not setting the value, meaning the `BindingMode = OneWay` or in this case `BindMode = OneTime` then you are binding to it just fine.

However, your `IsBusy` isn't firing properly because you're setting the backing field and the notification is never sent.

In the  `VideoPlayer_PropertyChanged` handler change `isBusy = false ...or true` to `IsBusy = false ...or true`

I also wouldn't call it a Bindable Property... It's just a property and you can bind to any public or internal properties (internal if same assembly).  The way to make a property bindable in a sense you're referring is to set it up with notifications like you've done with `IsBusy` or if using `DependencyObject` use `DependencyProperty` or if it's a collection use `INotifyCollectionChanged` most popularly in the form of an `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I'm still learning the terminology and the inner workings of C# so this is very helpful.  Yeah, my XAML does not include a `VideoState` binding.  I have it all in the `RoxViewModel` class in my post.  As for replacing `isBusy` to `IsBusy` in the `VideoPlayer_PropertyChanged` handler, it doesn't seem like it's working...  Interestingly, setting the property `isBusy = true` or `IsBusy = true` for both `if` and `else` events does not actually make the `IsBusy` binding to actually be true (!)  Is my handler set properly?

Comment: @TomF what are you binding to?  Can you show me the code that you're using the binding with?

Comment: Sure thing, I have updated my original post to include the XAML that has the bindings.  Also interesting - I have used breakpoints in my code and I found out that my code goes through the `get` but never enters `set` (unless it doesn't need to because I'm not initiating something?).  I'm looking more into backing fields as well.

Comment: @TomF  I don't see where ```Videoplayer_PropertyChanged``` is wired up.  Is this method being hit any?  Place a break point there.  If so then the set for ```IsBusy``` should also be getting hit.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption - `Videoplayer_PropertyChanged` is not wired up.  I am assuming I hook it up similarly to `OnPropertyChanged` but using `(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)` ?  If it is I'm not too sure how to fill in those criteria, still hitting the books

Comment: This will not be hooked up automatically unless it's in the code behind.  I believe you're confusing binding and MVVM principles.  This isn't designed correctly.  I'd like to help more but have to get my own work done but later, if I can, I'll explain it better.  Probably best in link to a guide though to be honest because I think it's going to be alot.

Comment: That's fine, I will look more into it.  Did not expect the task to be so difficult!  If you have more info regarding the task, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey @Michael Puckett II, I'm not sure if you are still getting notifications for this thread, but I'm still hitting a wall on this one.  I don't know if this is frowned upon here or not - but would it be possible for me to pay you for a service of solving this one problem?

Comment: You don't need to pay me... Just,send the project to Michael_puckett_ii@hotmail.com and I'll help you out.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you Michael!  God bless!  I will send you an e-mail shortly, my e-mail is tomf3463@gmail.com